# connect to Oracle Express Edition via JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

i'm trying to coneect to ORACLE EXPRESS EDITION 10G using JDBC

But i'm getting an error :"the network adapter could not establish the connection"
I used following URL

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE", "hr", "hr");
```

I even used

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521:XE");
```

in this case i got "Listener currently does not know of SID in connection descriptor"

Comment: Are you sure your database is configured correctly? The errors seem like there is a problem with the configuration.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. You are mixing the old SID based syntax with the new service name based syntax. It's either: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE`

Comment: can you tell me complete syntax along with username,password.